# why select a more column make mysql use index condition pushdown?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

in the test database employees, employees has 300,000+ rows.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    birth_date  DATE            NOT NULL,
    first_name  VARCHAR(14)     NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
    gender      ENUM ('M','F')  NOT NULL,    
    hire_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no)
);

alter table employees add index IDX_LAST_NAME(last_name);
```

```
explain
select last_name, emp_no
from employees
where last_name in ('Aamodt', 'Aaaa', 'Ab', 'Ac')
order by last_name asc, emp_no asc
limit 100;
```

shows
[image]
It uses covering index for where filter and order by.

explain format=JSON

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "43.97"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "employees",
        "access_type": "range",
        "possible_keys": [
          "IDX_LAST_NAME"
        ],
        "key": "IDX_LAST_NAME",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "last_name"
        ],
        "key_length": "66",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 208,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 208,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "using_index": true,
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "23.17",
          "eval_cost": "20.80",
          "prefix_cost": "43.97",
          "data_read_per_join": "27K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "emp_no",
          "last_name"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "(`employees`.`employees`.`last_name` in ('Aamodt','Aaaa','Ab','Ac'))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While

```
explain
select last_name, emp_no, first_name
from employees
where last_name in ('Aamodt', 'Aaaa', 'Ab', 'Ac')
order by last_name asc, emp_no asc
limit 100;
```

shows
[image]

explain format=JSON

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "168.10"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "employees",
        "access_type": "range",
        "possible_keys": [
          "IDX_LAST_NAME"
        ],
        "key": "IDX_LAST_NAME",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "last_name"
        ],
        "key_length": "66",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 208,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 208,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "index_condition": "(`employees`.`employees`.`last_name` in ('Aamodt','Aaaa','Ab','Ac'))",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "147.30",
          "eval_cost": "20.80",
          "prefix_cost": "168.10",
          "data_read_per_join": "27K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "emp_no",
          "first_name",
          "last_name"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think it use IDX_LAST_NAME index for where filer and order by, but also need to retrieve full table rows.

But why the second SQL use index condition pushdown? Considering performance, does the
second SQL only take more cost for retrieving the full rows than the first SQL?

Comment: "Using index" means "covering"; "Using index condition" means "Index condition pushdown".  See OJones answer for more details.

Comment: @Rick James, I understand that the first SQL use convering index, the second SQL use Index condition pushdown. But I don't know the second SQL use Index condition pushdown for what? It just select a column not in the index: "first_name". I mean, isn't Index condition pushdown used for filtering?

Comment: Please provide the _text_ version of `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`  It will make it easier to explain that pushdown.

Answer (score 1):

These must be InnoDB tables. Indexes in that storage engine always have the PK appended to them, so your first query can be *covered* by the index on `last_name`.

Your second query probably uses your index on `last_name` for two things: finding the right rows and handling the `ORDER BY last_name ... LIMIT 100` operation without sorting the entire table. But it still must hit the [clustered index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html) implementing the primary key to retrieve the `first_name`.

To see more details use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE FORMAT=TREE` on MySQL or `ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON` on MariaDB to retrieve your execution plan.

To know whether your query is unacceptably slow, you need to test it.  If your second query is unacceptably slow you can create an index to cover it.

```sql
CREATE INDEX l_e_f ON employees (last_name, emp_id, first_name);
```

Comment: And DROP your index on just `last_name`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try EXPLAIN ANALYZE.